# How to know if the method is static using java instrumentation and ASM

Tags: java, instrumentation

I am using java instrumentation and ASM to manipulate java byte code.
How can I know if a function is static?

I tried using Modifier.isStatic but I cant run it inside the instrumentation. 
Can I know this using ASM functions?

I need it in order to get the function arguments. If the function is not static, the this object sits in index 0 at the stack

Answer (score 2):

Write your own Class Visitor, then override "visitMethod"

```
  @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
                                     String signature, String[] exceptions) 
    {
        // for a single flag bit, test against zero is sufficient
        boolean isStatic = (access & Opcodes.ACC_STATIC) != 0;
        // do something else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the localVariableNodes of the MethodNode in question.  If the first Variable in the list you get from calling "MethodNodeName".localVariables is an instance of the class to which the MethodNode belongs then the MethodNode is not static, and vice versa.

To get the parameters of a method use this

```
String raw = Arrays.toString(Type.getArgumentTypes("MethodNodeName".desc));
int numParams = (Arrays.asList(raw.split(",[ ]*"))).size();
```

this will return the number of params in a method.  Since the first variables put into the localVariable list are the params it is a simple matter of extracting the first [1,numParams] variables to get the params.

For example given

```
public void methodName(int arg0, int arg1){ ....}
```

the first three variables in the local variable list would be starting with index 0
("object of type which method belongs to", "object of type int", "object of type int", ....)

where as

```
public static void methodName(int arg0, int arg1){ ....}
```

would yield ("object of type int", "object of type int", ...)

Please note that this is making the assumption that the method in question doesn't take as its first parameter an object of the class to which the method belongs.

cheers

EDIT:

As an alternative solution you can check to see if localVariableNodes.get(0).equals("this") is true;  If it is true the method is non static and vice versa.  If the method does not have localVariables then the method is static

Answer (score 0):

You can pass access variable to your method visitor from the class visitor when overriding:

```
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
                                     String signature, String[] exceptions)
```

If access value is bigger than Opcodes.ACC_STATIC, it seems to indicate that method is static.

Example of class visitor:

```
public class LogMethodClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {

    public LogMethodClassVisitor(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
                                     String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature,
                exceptions);
        return new LogMethodVisitor(this.api, mv, name, desc, access);
    }
}
```

Example of MethodVisitorConstructor:

```
public class LogMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {
    private boolean isAnnotationPresent = false;
    private String methodName;
    private String description;
    private boolean isStatic;

    public LogMethodVisitor(int api, MethodVisitor methodVisitor, String methodName, String description, int access) {
        super(api, methodVisitor);
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.description = description;
        isStatic = (access > Opcodes.ACC_STATIC);
    }
```